# How does Shopify's {% javascript %} tag work?

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I haven't been able to find anything on how this tag works. Why should I use the {% javascript %} instead of HTML script tag? Is there any difference?  I've checked the Shopify [cheatsheet](https://www.shopify.com/partners/shopify-cheat-sheet) which describes every other tag, as well as sifted through several pages of google and haven't found anything substantial.

Comment: https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/sections#javascript-and-stylesheet-tags Thats what i found on the javascript tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are adding the `{% javascript %}` tag in a theme `section` context then:

> Sections can bundle their own script and style assets using the `javascript` and `stylesheet` tags. You should only need to use this for sections that are meant to be reused or installed on multiple themes or shops.

> The scripts for all sections are concatenated into a single file by Shopify and injected into `content_for_header`. The injected `<script>` is set to load asynchronously with the `defer` attribute. The `javascript` tag is wrapped in a self-executing anonymous function and a try/catch, which means that variables get defined inside a closure and runtime exceptions won't affect other sections.

[Reference](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/sections#javascript-and-stylesheet-tags)

Comment: That is exactly the information I was looking for. On another note, does that mean that the [recommendation to wrap your JS code in a closure](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/include-javascript-in-shopify-themes) is unnecessary in the section context since that happens automatically?

Comment: Correct! if you are going to use `{%.javascript %}` tag in that case you don't need to wrap your Js code in a closure.

Comment: How can i defer load a script using liquids {% javascript %} and {% endjavascript %} ?

Answer (score 2):

It is simply a convenience for you. It offers you no special capabilities. It nice because to the less than stellar technical person, someone who might get a little Liquid but not much else, it is pretty clear that the stuff inside the tag is likely Javascript. They recommend you only use these tags if your section is meant for a widely distributed theme, and or many shops. In other words, if you like script tags, go ahead and use them, no harm done.